# EXECUTE AS and OPENQUERY linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a problem. When I use the statement execute as and then want to use that principle to open data from a linked server, the openquery query is not run with the User2 principle, but with the login (User1)that runs the query. I deliberately gave User1 the wrong credentials for the linked server. The following query gives an error

```
Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Login failed for user 'LinkedServerUser1'.
```

Query:

```
USE Database1
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'User2'

IF EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    OPENQUERY(LinkedServer1,'
    SELECT
    name
    ,state
    ,state_desc
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE name = ''DatabaseLinked1'' AND state = 0
    '
    )
)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'test'
END

REVERT
```

In need this to work because normally this query will be run by the SQL Server Agent, and I don't want to grant the SQL Server Agent User access to the linked server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I already found the solution. Adding

```
GO
```

after EXECUTE AS, solves the problem...